# Storing a service account with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, security, password-encryption

I'm writing a small HipChat plugin using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy with local database. I want the admin to be able to setup a service account for an external service this is meant to integrate with.

Because the username/password of the service accounts needs to be stored so they can be used by the integration to make API calls I can't use non-reversible hashing methods for storing the password.

Are there recommendations for how to approach this so that the passwords or the database can be better secured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encrypt your data before storing them in your database. [`pycrypto`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) is one of the libraries that you can utilize.

> It is easy to encrypt text using DES/ECB with pycrypto. The key
>   ‘10234567’ is 8 bytes and the text’s length needs to be a multiple of
>   8 bytes. We picked ‘abcdefgh’ in this example.

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import DES
>>> des = DES.new('01234567', DES.MODE_ECB)
>>> text = 'abcdefgh'
>>> cipher_text = des.encrypt(text)
>>> cipher_text
'\xec\xc2\x9e\xd9] a\xd0'
>>> des.decrypt(cipher_text)
'abcdefgh'
```

[here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-and-cryptography-with-pycrypto/#a_2) is a short article about `pycrypto`.

Comment: What would you recommend for the key? Single key (using the Flask app's secret key) or a different key per record? And what recommendations would you have for storing those keys?

Comment: Well I'm not a security expert and I don't have many experiences in maintaining sensitive applications. I suggest you ask these questions in: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: After reading a bit more from examples on the security section I think I will be applying your suggestion using AES instead of DES.